# Изменение размера body по размеру toggle меню и обратно

Tags: jquery, меню, menu, height, toggle

Нужно чтобы при вызове меню, скроллинг страницы осуществлялся только в пределах этого меню, я решил сделать это путем изменения размера body. Вот только скрипт работает в одну сторону. Т.е. размер не изменяется при повторном клике, когда прячется меню. Вопрос ламерский чуть более, чем полностью наверное, помогите плз

```js
var menuHeight = $('nav').height();

$('.menu-btn').click(function() {
  $('nav').slideToggle();
  if($('nav').is(":visible")) {
    $('body').height(menuHeight);
  } else {
   $('body').height(1000);
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}


.menu-btn {
  display: block;
  background-color: #191919;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  display: none;
 
}
nav ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 display: block;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
}
nav ul li a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-btn">open</a>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">point</a></li>
    <li><a href="">point</a></li>
    <li><a href="">point</a></li>
    <li><a href="">point</a></li>
    <li><a href="">point</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Сейчас заметил что тут скрипт не работает, в отличие от jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```js
var menuHeight = $('nav').height();

$('.menu-btn').click(function() {
  if($('nav').is(":hidden")) {
   $('nav').slideToggle();
    $('body').height(menuHeight);
  } else if (($('nav').is(":visible"))) {
  $('nav').slideToggle();
   $('body').height(1000);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

всё решил) Но может есть попроще способ и правильнее ?